# JavaScript variable isolation in constructors of separate objects

Tags: javascript, variables, object, constructor, scope

Looking at this code it should produce output "TEST1"+"TEST2" however I get "TEST2" twice:

```
function TEST1(){
   var __construct = function () { this.box = { test_ : function () {console.log('TEST1')} }}
   __construct()
}

TEST1.prototype = {t: function(){ return box.test_()} }


function TEST2(){
   var __construct = function () { this.box = { test_ : function () {console.log('TEST2')} }}
   __construct()
}

TEST2.prototype = {t: function(){ return box.test_()}}

var t1 = new TEST1()
var t2 = new TEST2()
t1.t()
t2.t()
```

If I rename "box" in second function I get correct output:

```
function TEST2(){
   var __construct = function () { this.box_ = { test_ : function () {console.log('TEST2')} }}
   __construct()
}

TEST2.prototype = {t: function(){ return box_.test_()}}
```

Why is there this what appears a variable isolation issue?

Comment: It's because when you call __construct() the *this* value inside the __contruct is the global object, hence the box object got created on the global object. Hence they the second box definition overrides the first definition.

Comment: Is __construct more than a function name in the code?

Comment: That code doesn't make any sense...

Comment: The following answer may be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because when you call __construct() the *this* value inside the __contruct is the global object, hence the box object got created on the global object. This is because Javascript has function scope, and nested functions do not get the *this* value of it's parent functions. Hence nested functions have an execution context of the global scope.

When you wrote:

```
var t1 = new TEST1();
```

The __construct() call created a box property on the global(window) object.

Then, when you wrote

```
var t2 = new TEST2()
```

The __construct() call saw that the global object already had a box property and over-wrote it.

Hence they the second box definition overrides the first definition.

@Bergi wanted a fix, though this is not an issue, and just correct behavior. :)

```
function TEST1(){
   var __construct = function () { this.box = { test_ : function () {console.log('TEST1')} }};
   __construct.call(this);
}

TEST1.prototype = {t: function(){ return this.box.test_()} };


function TEST2(){
   var __construct = function () { this.box = { test_ : function () {console.log('TEST2')} }};
   __construct.call(this);
}

TEST2.prototype = {t: function(){ return this.box.test_()}};

var t1 = new TEST1();
var t2 = new TEST2();
t1.t();
t2.t();
```

Comment: Realized same thing. I will name them box_test1, box_test2. I think it may be a good thing to try: having private object functions in global(window) under different vars (box_test1, 2 in this case).

Comment: I actually meant to completely remove those local `__construct` functions, but +1 nonetheless.

Comment: Does this code work? I get "Cannot read property 'test_' of undefined " error on "return this.box.test_()" line

Comment: @Gonki: Take some time and understand how it works. It will be well worth the time spent.

Comment: I've been reading up on object construction techniques. It may be that the configuration described here is a rugged one. All object data and functions are kept private and prototype provides only marshaling calls from public to private. I was missing the call() function (although call() did occur to me as a possible solution but I didn't see how to use it correctly with "this").